# How to make multiple R plots use full page

Tags: r, knitr

Sorry if this is a duplicate. I can't seem to find the solution on here or on various other sites explaining par and fig.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,2))

sec = df
sec$new[sec$sector=='Apartment']<-TRUE
sec=subset(sec,sec$new==TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.05,0.5,0.66,1),new=TRUE)
scatter.smooth(sec$Look_Back_Months,sec$Ann_TRT_Spread*100, degree =4 , col = "red",pch = 16,main = 'Apartment', ylab = "Annu. Total Return %",xlab = "Months in Look Back Period")
sec = df
sec$new[sec$sector=='Office']<-TRUE
sec=subset(sec,sec$new==TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.5,0.95,0.66,1),new=TRUE)
scatter.smooth(sec$Look_Back_Months,sec$Ann_TRT_Spread*100, degree =4 , col = "red",pch = 16,main = 'Office', ylab = "Annu. Total Return %",xlab = "Months in Look Back Period")

sec = df
sec$new[sec$sector=='Industrial']<-TRUE
sec=subset(sec,sec$new==TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.5,0.95,0.33,0.66),new=TRUE)
scatter.smooth(sec$Look_Back_Months,sec$Ann_TRT_Spread*100, degree =4 , col = "red",pch = 16,main = 'Industrial', ylab = "Annu. Total Return %",xlab = "Months in Look Back Period")

sec = df
sec$new[sec$sector=='Mall']<-TRUE
sec=subset(sec,sec$new==TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.05,0.5,0.33,0.66),new=TRUE)
scatter.smooth(sec$Look_Back_Months,sec$Ann_TRT_Spread*100, degree =4 , col = "red",pch = 16,main = 'Mall', ylab = "Annu. Total Return %",xlab = "Months in Look Back Period")

sec = df
sec$new[sec$sector=='Strip Center']<-TRUE
sec=subset(sec,sec$new==TRUE)
par(fig=c(0.05,0.5,0,0.33),new=TRUE)
scatter.smooth(sec$Look_Back_Months,sec$Ann_TRT_Spread*100, degree =4 , col = "red",pch = 16,main = 'Strip Center', ylab = "Annu. Total Return %",xlab = "Months in Look Back Period")
```

The above code produces the following page, when i Knit

[image]

Why is it not using the full page? 
I have tried experimenting with par, with fig, but I can't yield a full page.

Sorry for the redaction of the plots. The data is mildly sensitive.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to set `fig.width` and `fig.height`. See [`knitr::opts_chunk`](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/).

Comment: If you need more help, I suggest making a reproducible question by having a complete R-markdown document with sample data and sample plots. An added benefit is that it would not require you to post-process the image to redact sensitive components.

Comment: Thank you. ended up using ```{r message=FALSE, warning=FALSE,out.width='.49\\linewidth', fig.asp=.85, fig.ncol = 2} as the chunk option, and it worked.